# Why PCA performed on two similar data sets result in different number of components?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I have two data sets (2048 dimensions) collected under slightly different circumstances. I am using PCA to reduce the dimension of the data before passing it further for classification. Both data sets are spectra of the same alloy samples collected with slightly different lasers.

My problem is that of the two sets of *visually* similar data one requires 60 components and the other 275 given the same amount of variance retention (99.9%).

I would like to ask is there some technique that would allow me to identify the source (features or combinations of thereof) of this behavior? Is there some standard method other then simply comparing the total variance?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the last 215 of those 275 aren't just artifacts from measurement variability ("noise")? For that matter, what evidence do you have that *any* of the principal components are meaningful?

Comment: @whuber I am still a bit new to this, what would be a good starting point to verify the meaningfulness of the principal components? My only evidence so far is that the classification of the reduced dimension data is working with 99.5% success rate and good degree of confidence.

Comment: One approach is to vary the data in a way consistent with its inherent uncertainty. If such variation produces the same number of components every time, perhaps it is meaningful to retain that number. But if the number of components changes a lot, then you should suspect that some of them are mere artifacts, resulting from arbitrary and random aspects of the data.

Answer (score 2):

99.9% is a lot of retained variance. Without seeing the data or knowing more about your experiment, I'd guess you have different noise levels in the two conditions.

I would suggest making a scree plot (variance explained per PC) and looking for an "elbow" or kink, like this one from the [Statistica docs](http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=glossary/GlossaryTwo/S/ScreePlotScreeTest).

[image: here]

In this case, you'd consider retaining 3 factors, since the others have only minimal explanatory power. There are other rules of thumb, but this is a reasonably place to start.

Comment: The 99.9% has no real basis behind it other then that the classification was working with 99.5% success rate and the initial resulting number of principle components was not too large.

Comment: The experiment itself is very simple: evaluate performance of two similar lasers (same triggering, same spectrometer, same sample material, similar energy) for the purposes of classifying alloys.

Comment: Do you have a sense for the quality of your data? Retaining 99.9% of the variance is essentially claiming that < 0.1% of your data is noise. If everything is nice and deterministic, that could be true; I mostly work on "messy" problems, which is why I'm skeptical.

Comment: I have attempted to do Variance vs. Num. of PC analysis and it seems that both methods require same number of PCs for up to 99% variance retention: 20 components. Past 20 PCs, the slope of the curve is only slightly different but it is what drives the number of PCs to 275.

Comment: And I know that the data I am dealing with is noisy and messy. I am only using PCA to reduce the dimension from 2048 to something less to make the classifier training simpler.

Comment: In that case, I'm gonna double-down on "you're retaining too many PCs and should use fewer". I wouldn't be too surprised if dramatically reducing the number has a minimal effect on your classifier's performance too.

(By the way, I didn't mean to impugn the quality of your data--it actually sounds pretty clean. I've been dealing with biological stuff and there's no way it's 99.9% (or realistically, 90%) signal.)